# Why doesn't the value get saved into SharedPreferences on app restart?

Tags: java, android

I have a function called cup and I want to know why this code is not saving the value of `i`.  Why does it return `i` to `0` when I close the app?

```
public void cup(View view) {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Water", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    i=sharedPreferences.getInt("Cup", 0);

    final int[] imageArray = {
       R.drawable.waterdrop1, R.drawable.waterdrop2, R.drawable.waterdrop3,          
       R.drawable.waterdrop4, R.drawable.waterdrop5, R.drawable.waterdrop6, 
       R.drawable.waterdrop
    };

    imageView7.setImageResource(imageArray[i]);

    i++;
    if (i > 6) {
        i = 6;
    }
    editor.putInt("Cup", i);
    editor.commit();      
}
```

Knowing that cup is onclick function

Comment: What is your output of `i` and what is the expected one?

Comment: when we click on the image i must increase by 1, the maximum value of it is 6

Comment: I've noticed that `i` is not a local variable. Is there something else that interacts (modifies) `i`? What exactly do you mean with "... return `i` to `0` when I close the app"? I assume `i` is `0` in the first call to `cup()` after an app restart?

Comment: You could do `editor.apply()` instead, but it does not make sense why the value would reset if this is the only code that modifies the Water SharedPreferences and the app doesn't clear its memory on exit.

Comment: I tried to change the variable to local and it worked, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Your code look correct for the `SharedPreferences` part. I believe there might be another part of your code not shown that could be causing the problem.

That being said, I would suggest using `editor.apply()` instead of `.commit()` for the write to be handled in the background.

Comment: Thank you, but I have already tried the editor.apply() but the problem stayed the same.

Comment: As I said the problem is somewhere else in your code. the `.apply()` is just a suggestion, not a fix for your problem.